# Magento 1.9.1.0 remove Sort By and Show per page

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I remove completely Sort By and Show per page from toolbar on product listing with grid view in Magento 1.9.1.0. I have only a few products on my shop so now I don't need sorting. What file should I edit and how to change code in this file.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the bar with CSS or remove it from your template.

**css way**

```
.toolbar { display:none; }
```

**template way**

Look in `catalog/product/list.phtml` and remove or comment out:

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar_top.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

enter on top of the template:

```
return;
```

Comment: Except that this is not a clean solution: Which template? The answer won't help anybody as it stands.